# How do I add a count result to a valuemap?

Tags: gremlin

I've worked out a traversal but would like to change how the result is structured to make it cleaner to extract in my Java code.

I want all the group vertices that my user is a member of along with a count of the group's total membership.  I've used valueMap as that makes it nice to extract in the client Java

```
g.V().has('user','name','james').out('member').group().by(valueMap(true, 'name','image')).by(inE('member').count()).unfold()
```

which gives me

```
==>{image=[images/groups/group6.jpg], label=group, name=[Boxing Lovers], id=c1db7d33-a24c-4981-8ee8-950371789637}=10
==>{image=[images/groups/group4.jpg], label=group, name=[Hiking Disciples], id=d2da3866-1922-4c00-8895-21ab2e099243}=11.
```

How would I add the membership count to the HashMap with the group details, like below?

```
==>{image=[images/groups/group6.jpg], label=group, name=[Boxing Lovers], id=c1db7d33-a24c-4981-8ee8-950371789637, membership=10}
==>{image=[images/groups/group4.jpg], label=group, name=[Hiking Disciples], id=d2da3866-1922-4c00-8895-21ab2e099243, membership=11}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `valueMap` you could use `project`. Here's an example using the air-routes graph.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('region','US-TX').
               project('id','label','city','count').
                 by(id).
                 by(label).
                 by('city').
                 by(out().count()).
               limit(3)
==>[id:3,label:airport,city:Austin,count:80]
==>[id:8,label:airport,city:Dallas,count:250]
==>[id:11,label:airport,city:Houston,count:197]
```

Comment: thanks Kelvin, tweaked it to use project and its what I want. Appreciated. `g.V().has('user','name','james').out('member').project('id', 'name','image', 'count').by(id).by('name').by('image').by(inE('member').count())`

 `==>{id=c1db7d33-a24c-4981-8ee8-950371789637, name=Boxing Lovers, image=images/groups/group6.jpg, count=11}
==>{id=d2da3866-1922-4c00-8895-21ab2e099243, name=Hiking Disciples, image=images/groups/group4.jpg, count=11}`